# How to create anchor element with text and bootstrap icon

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create a element with text and bootstrap icon. The HTML looks like this

```
<a>
  Edit
  <i class="icon-pencil" />
</a>
```

How to get this DOM element using jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('div').html('<a>  Edit  <i class="icon-pencil" /></a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var anchor = $('<a>').text('Edit').append( $('<i class="icon-pencil"/>') );
```

or

```
 var anchor = $('<a>').text('Edit').append( $('<i>').addClass('icon-pencil') );
```

and don't forget to insert this anchor into your document:

```
 $('#some-container').append(anchor);
```